# What is the accepted way to setup pass parameters to base class?

Tags: java, oop

I want to move as much of the repeatable code into the base class as possible, but I find myself needing to pass variables from the derived class back to the base class.

`myClass` must have a parameter-less initialize method and is "setup" through `myInterface.setup()`.

How can I force the extender of `myBase` to set the variables without having to check they are set everytime from `someBaseMethod()`

```
interface myInterface
{
    void setup(String myStr);
    void someBaseMethod();
}

abstract class myBase implements myInterface
{
    String myStr = null;

    protected abstract String getMyStr();

    // called lots of times.
    public void someBaseMethod()
    {
        if (myStr == null) myStr = getMyStr();

        // ...
    }
}

class myClass extends myBase
{
    String s = null;

    public void setup(String myStr)
    {
        s = myStr;
    }

    protected String getMyStr()
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use a parameter in the constructor of the base class. That way, every sub-class must set it before it can be instantiated.

Comment: I suggest to use Constructor for that matter in case you do not need to open resources in setup method

Comment: common naming convention = CapTheFirstLetter

Comment: @CarlosGavidia can't do that as I don't know the variable when the class is instantiated.

Comment: You really, really want to avoid having this kind of gradual initialisation of a class. Why don't you know the value of the variable when the class is instantiated? Can you do anything about that?

Comment: Not really no, because I am compiling and creating an instance of the class at runtime, I don't know what parameters the class is going to require to instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

If `protected String getMyStr()` is implemented in subclasses and returns implementation specific string, then you shouldn't keep it in base class as field `String myStr`.

Just create a local variable:

```
public void someBaseMethod() {
    final String myStr = getMyStr();
    .....
```

Also, if you need to run setup method before anything else, then you might want to have a boolean flag, that indicates that fields are setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `boolean` variable in your class `myBase` which indicates that the class s correctly initialized.

E.g.

```
class MyBase {
    private initialized = false; // Only for documentation as a bolean is always initialied to false
    // further variables and methods
}
```

Then you only need to check that variable:

```
if (initialized) {
    // Do your stuff
} else {
    // Do some error handling
}
```

Please note that in Java lasses normally beginn with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems very clumsy for what you are trying to do. Why don't you do it like this:

```
interface myInterface
{
    void setup(String myStr);
    void someBaseMethod();
}

abstract class myBase implements myInterface
{
    private String myStr = null;

    protected String getMyStr()
    {
        return myStr;
    }

    protected void setMyStr(String value)
    {
        myStr = value;
    }

    // called lots of times.
    public void someBaseMethod()
    {
        // do stuff with myStr
    }
}

class myClass extends myBase
{
    public void setup(String myStr)
    {
        setMyStr(myStr);
    }
}
```

Or did I understand your requirements wrong?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the extending class does not need to call `setMyStr`...i'd prefer they have to explicitly call it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to ensure this elegantly. My advice is to just write good and exessive comments and tests and rely on the programmers capability.